SUMIF only if cell value is "String"
I have a simple Excel datasheet that I use to sum up different ticket types based on skills (data, onsite, remote, etc). The sheet works great but an additional column was added called Direction (inbound and repeat) and I only want the sheet to sum up the ticket types based on skills if the Direction is inbound.  How would I go about doing this using SUMIF?
My current formula is =SUMIF(Data!F:F,A2,Data!H:H)
Data! is the raw data sheet.
F is the skill column
A2 lists the skill names
H displays 1 if a ticket was submitted
Column AC lists the direction.
I hope this makes sense. TIA!
I've tried using =IF(Data!AC:AC,"Inbound";(=SUMIF(Data!F:F,A2,Data!H:H)) but this doesn't seem to do anything.
I've also tried using SUMIFS, =SUMIFS((Data!F:F,A2,Data!H:H,Data!AC:AC,"Inbound") but this produces a #SPILL error.
Any assistance would be appreciated.
Adding sample data.  This is a simplified form of my workbook.
Sheet 1 - Data



Skill
Offered
Direction




Data
1
Inbound


Remote
1
Repeat


Tech
1
Inbound


Data
1
Repeat


Remote
1
Inbound


Data
1
Inbound



Sheet 2 - Results



Skill
Offered




Data
2


Remote
1


Tech
1




Can you post some sample data and desired outputs?

If you have several conditions, try using SumIFS instead of Sumif
=SUMIFS(Data!H:H,Data!F:F,A2,Data!G:G,"inbound")



Here are few alternative ways one could try :


• Option One:
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A7,SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,A2:A7,C2:C7,"Inbound")))


• Option Two:
=LET(
     _Skill, A2:A7,
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Skill),
     HSTACK(_Uniq, SUMIFS(B2:B7,_Skill,_Uniq,C2:C7,"Inbound")))


• Option Three:
=GROUPBY(A2:A7,B2:B7,SUM,,0,,C2:C7="Inbound")


Or, take the whole array and use the following:
=LET(
     _Data, A2:C7,
     _Skill, INDEX(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Skill),
     HSTACK(_Uniq, SUMIFS(INDEX(_Data,,2),_Skill,_Uniq, INDEX(_Data,,3),"Inbound")))



I realized that I was getting the #spill error as I had my formula in the wrong order. Once I corrected it and used SUMIFS, everything worked.
